# Deselect a ListViewItem from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I have Two ListViews  the first is a MultipleSelection Enabled ListView. When the user clicks an item from the first ListView it is added to the second ListView, and when he deselects an item from the first listView it is deleted from the second ListView.

My problem now is I want the user to be able to delete a ListViewItem from the second ListView(already implemented) and have the item be deselected in the firstListView. I can delete the item no problem just need a way to deselect that  item in the first ListView

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <RelativePanel >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" RelativePanel.LeftOf="MoveButton"/>
                        <Button  Name="MoveButton" Command="{Binding ElementName=NaughtySelectionList, Path=DataContext.MoveCommand}" 
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"  Content="+"  
                                 Style="{StaticResource ButtonClearStyle}"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
                                 RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate> 

        </ListView>
        <ListView Name="NaughytSelectedList" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedNaughtyChildren}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <RelativePanel >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" RelativePanel.LeftOf="MoveBackButton"  />
                        <Button Name="MoveBackButton" 
                                Command="{Binding ElementName=NaughytSelectedList, Path=DataContext.MoveBackCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"  Content="✖"  
                                Style="{StaticResource ButtonClearStyle}" 
                                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
    private Child selectedChild ;
    public Child SelectedChild
    {
        get { return selectedChild; }
        set { selectedChild = value;


            base.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private DelegateCommand<IList<Object>> selectionChangedCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<IList<Object>> SelectionChangedCommand
        => selectionChangedCommand ?? (selectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<IList<object>>(AddToNaughty, CanAddToNaughty));
    private bool CanAddToNaughty(IList<object> arg)
    {
        return true;

    }

    private void AddToNaughty(IList<object> currentSelection)
{

        var currentSelectionCollection= new ObservableCollection<Child>();

        foreach (var child in currentSelection )
        {
            currentSelectionCollection.Add(child as Child);  
        }

        foreach (var child in currentSelectionCollection)
        {
            if (!SelectedNaughtyChildren.Contains(child))
                SelectedNaughtyChildren.Add(child);
        }


        //Check if an item has been deselected.
        var copyOfSelectedNaughtyChildren =  new ObservableCollection<Child>(SelectedNaughtyChildren);
            var deselectedItems = from child in copyOfSelectedNaughtyChildren
                            where !currentSelectionCollection.Contains(child)
                            select child;


        //Remove the DeselectedItem.
        foreach (var child in deselectedItems)
        {
            SelectedNaughtyChildren.Remove(child);
        }       
    }

    private DelegateCommand<int> moveBackCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<int> MoveBackCommand
        => moveBackCommand ?? (moveBackCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(DeleteChild, CanDeleteChild));



    private bool CanDeleteChild(int arg)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void DeleteChild(int id)
    {
        var childMatch = from child in SelectedNaughtyChildren
                         where child.Id == id
                         select child;

        var childToRemove = childMatch.First();
        if (childToRemove != null)
            SelectedNaughtyChildren.Remove(childToRemove);
         //Hear I want to deselect the item from the first ListView
         // setting selected item to null deselects all the items.
        SelectedChild = null;

    }
}
```

Edit: I Added some images to show the functionality I want. I have this working but only by using the code behind. I would like to achieve this in the ViewModel if possible.

[So the user selects some items and they appear in the ListView to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHraQ.png)

[When the user deletes and item from the right it gets deselected in the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj3mi.png)

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: No, unfortunately the only fix I found was to update the listView.SelectedItems from the code behind. I can't see a logical way for the ViewModel to update a listViews SelectedItems. If remove an item from the observableCollection then it will delete it from the binding ListView.

Comment: I've updated the post with some images to show how it works

Comment: Yes you have to remove item from ListView selecteditems. I just told to use ObservableCollection items to compare the items

Comment: You ca do that in Viewmodel also. All you want is Listview's reference. You can listen to Listview's loaded event in viewmodel and get the listview's reference,and save it in ViewModel's some property,use it later

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the item from `SelectedItems` list of `firstlistview`
Here is the code

```
foreach(var item in FirstListView.Items)//or use firstlistview observable collection
{
//Compare item to be deselected
  if(childToRemove  == item)
     FirstListView.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't select the Item property of an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I did not mean to select item property in Observablecollection. Use observable collection directly or if you have access to ListView you can get its Items property